# Ruby and Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I followed these instructions, installed passenger, but the web page is still not resolving to the ruby app. It just shows the files. Please help!

https://github.com/redbooth/teambox/wiki/installing-on-ubuntu

Comment: Does your Apache error log say anything?

Answer (score 2):

By "Ruby app", I assume you refer to an app built with [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org), the most common Ruby web application framework.

Make sure that you set the web root to the `/public` directory, your `PassengerRoot` and `PassengerRuby` lines are in the right file (bear in mind that you should not copy those, but instead what the installer told you!), and that you included the `RailsEnv` line in your site's configuration. (If you are on Rails 3, use `RackEnv`, instead.)

But these are just generic tips for likely issues. It helps if you have some more specific error messages, if any exist...

Comment: okay I got it resolving. Now it is giving this error:

Permission denied - /root/.bundle/ruby/1.8/specifications

specifications is a directory